# Oracle systimestamp result differs in db server and client

Tags: oracle, timezone, session, nls

I am getting some strange output while executing the below command on db server and on client machine connected to same db server.

### On DB server

```
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

systimestamp

25-JUN-15 06.16.13.424135 PM +08:00
```

### On Client Machine

```
SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP

25-JUN-15 02.16.57.936662 AM -08:00
```

### Below output for Reference

```
SQL>  select dbtimezone, sessiontimezone from dual;

DBTIMEZONE                     SESSIONTIMEZONE

+00:00                            +08:00
```

Comment: ,Have you check out client machine timezone. which OS client machine are running?

Comment: client and db os machine are same with the same timezone i.e. +0800

Comment: You can change session timezone (on client right after establishing connection) : `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '+00:00'`.  You may write `AFTER LOGON` trigger to do it automatically for each new connection. You can also change db timezone (which affects columns of `timestamp with local timezone` type). Another option is to have `at timezone ` clause in your queries

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to force any user settings and overwrite it by a logon trigger. User settings should stay user specific

Comment: `DBTIMEZOME` does NOT define the time zone of ` SYSTIMESTAMP` It is inherited from DB operating system.

Comment: Do you logon as user `oracle` at DB server?

Comment: yes.. sys as sysdba using os authentication

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, because your NLS settings differ on the server and on the client.

The NLS conversion always happens on the client side no matter what your server settings are.  Compare the output of these:

```
select * from nls_database_parameters;
select * from nls_session_parameters;
```

Comment: How to resolve this gap? As it is creating confusion while fetching the same report on db server and client.

Comment: Both the output are same..

Comment: select * from nls_instance_parameters;

Comment: All parameters are null except language and territory.

Comment: are you and the server in the same country or region?

Comment: Yes .. both the db server and client are on the same country.

Answer (score 0):

Timezone of `SYSTIMESTAMP` is taken from operating system. However, on operating system this can be user-specific.

Do you get different results when you do this on DB Server?

```
$ su oracle

$ setenv TZ America/Winnipeg
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> select systimestamp from dual;
...
SQL> exit

$ setenv TZ Europe/Zurich
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> select systimestamp from dual;
...
SQL> exit
```

Comment: No. I got the same result. from the above

Comment: Can you try to read `TZ` environment variable from the process where DB is running on. See here for details: [How to read environment variables of a process](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process)